# How to fix the below error in the simple chaser program in unity 3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am completely new to unity 3d and c sharp. I was designing a program in which a sphere is  chasing a cube . I tried but it's showing some error.

Error in the console :

```
Assets/chaserr.cs(8,40): error CS0019: Operator `-' cannot be applied to operands of type `UnityEngine.Transform' and `UnityEngine.Vector3'
Assets/chaserr.cs(11,38): error CS0019: Operator `+' cannot be applied to operands of type `UnityEngine.Vector3' and `float'
Assets/chaserr.cs(11,27): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Transform.Translate(UnityEngine.Vector3)' has some invalid arguments
Assets/chaserr.cs(11,27): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `object' expression to type `UnityEngine.Vector3'
```

Chaserr.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class chaserr : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform target;
    float speed = 8;
    void Update () {
        Vector3 displacement = target - transform.position;
        Vector3 direction = displacement.normalized;
        Vector3 velocity = direction * speed;
        transform.Translate (velocity + Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

move.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class move : MonoBehaviour {
    float speed = 10;
    void Update () {
        Vector3 input = new Vector3 (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical"));
        Vector3 direction = input.normalized;
        Vector3 velocity = direction * speed;
        Vector3 moveAmount = velocity * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate (moveAmount);

    }
}
```

if you want any other other information the please please comment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

`Vector3 displacement = target - transform.position;`

use

```
Vector3 displacement = target.position - transform.position;
```

AND

Instead of

`velocity + Time.deltaTime`

use

`velocity * Time.deltaTime`

Comment: it's asking for more 3minutes waiting time

Comment: after that i can do :)

Answer (score 1):

You can change your GameObject's velocity with Rigidbody (or Rigidbody2D for 2D game).

Firstly add Rigidbody component to your GameObject;

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public Rigidbody rigid;
    Vector3 yourVelocityVariable;

    void Start() {
        rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    void FixedUpdate() {
        rigid.velocity = yourVelocityVariable;            
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :) I appreciate your input but always address to solve the problem.